# Why does using void keyword before synchronized throws an error in Java, but the reverse works fine?

Tags: java, multithreading, keyword, synchronized

```
import java.util.*;

public class Deadlock extends Thread{

    private String name;    

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

    }

    public class MyObject{
        public void synchronized foo(String name) { //throws error saying 'Syntax error on token "void", volatile expected' 

        }       
    }   
}
```

But if, `public void synchronized` is changed to 
`public synchronized void`, everything is fine.

Why is that?

Comment: Because the *return type* must come directly before the method name – it is part of the method signature. All modifiers must precede the signature, and may appear in any order. Try to swap `public` and `synchronized` – it is just the same.

Comment: Modifiers are all listed before return type and method name, just a rule of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the Java Specification [8.4.3. Method modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3) which says:

```
MethodModifier:
    (one of) 
    Annotation public protected private 
    abstract static final synchronized native strictfp
```

Those must precede the return type, which comes as the last. The modifiers order does really not matter since they respect the return type comes as the last. That's why `public synchronized void` is valid.

Comment: Got it. So, it is a specification.

Answer (score 0):

What are you returning? Are you returning synchronized, or are you returning void? Since synchronized isn't something you can return, it has to be void. You see, the return type must always come immediately before the function name.